# What is the best way to learn differet code?

Tags: java, php, javascript, html, css

I am trying to a get a general grasp of a wide variety of different languages. Where is a good place to start learning? I would like to learn php, java, html, css, javascript.

I have been to w3schools http://www.w3schools.com

Are there any other great websites?

Comment: You should not use or link to [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com). It's not a reliable source of information and we don't want to encourage its use.

Comment: Good luck.Its a great website

Comment: google is your best friend.

Comment: please visit http://w3fools.com/

Comment: Discussion about encouraging/discouraging w3schools on SO can be found here.. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource

Comment: w3schools.com is terrible. Never go there. It is a dark place.

Comment: see [FAQ - don't ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) “Question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely try Codecademy http://www.codecademy.com. its free and they have great examples that you can work through.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the sites where you can learn java are :

[mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/) itself and links provided on [this](http://www.mkyong.com/featured/top-20-java-websites/) site.

Answer (score 0):

Read books! There's a lot of computer related book at Indigo. I think they are good, because it comes with example and it explains well